# Sequelize query return where like and where id match

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

The query should only return records that matches the employeeId and where filename like the context.data.filename but there is problem with the code it return even the employeeId didnt match . Any idea with this one guys ? Thank you.

#Code

```
const file = await context.service.Model.findAll({
    query: {
      employeeId: record.id,
      $or: [
        {
          filename: {
            $like: context.data.filename,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    paranoid: false,
  });
```

Comment: I think you would like to use $and to get employees with the given ID and the filename

Comment: @Sheelpriy , can you please post what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add OR, OR with single argument returns true. Try this:

```js
const file = await context.service.Model.findAll({
    query: {
     $and: [
        {
         employeeId: record.id,
          filename: {
            $like: context.data.filename,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    paranoid: false,
  });
```

Comment: Ive tried this sir it still return records that maches the filename but not the employeeId . it should only return if employeeId match and filename

Comment: write where instead of query, might help. Just updated the code snippet

Comment: when I use where it gives an error error: Error: Invalid value { '$like': 'DOC.doc' }

Comment: then you have to add $add instead of or. this will definitely work

Comment: Sorry but I did try it still the same , I did try using  where: {
      employeeId: record.id,
      filename: {
        [Op.like]: `%${context.data.filename}%`,
      },
    },

Comment: but that only return single record and not including maches